# Google Analytics API Python 'ClientOptions' object has no attribute 'api_audience'

Tags: python, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I was trying the quickstart API Python code for GA4 stated in the below URL and faced with the issue:
**AttributeError: 'ClientOptions' object has no attribute 'api_audience'**

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries#make_an_api_call

I have updated google-analytics-data and google-api-core packages but the problem seems to continue. When I try to run the code in Google Cloud Shell I don't face with any issue but I get the error while running on my computer. Any suggestions?

Comment: please edit your question and include [example] describe any issues you are having